# Windows Modules Installer Service - LDT information was not an integral multiple of the selector size

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

Since 17/05/2017, all of our Windows Server 2012 R2 VM's have been reporting the following error message whilst rebooting to install Windows Updates:

> Service Control Manager 7023
>
> The Windows Modules Installer service terminated with the following error:
>
> Indicates that the starting value for the LDT information was not an integral multiple of the selector size.

In addition, this seems to cause Domain Controllers to wait for a timeout, since they stop responding to ping requests for 1 hour +/- 1 minute each time.  Member servers don't seem to experience this delay, as far as I've noticed.

None of the 2012 R2 Hyper-V hosts have logged this error, but all of the 2012 R2 VM's have.

Numerous searches haven't turned anything up - I can't believe we're the only ones seeing this?